# I want time in HH:mm format from string in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to get two time values, which are in string format like this:

eg:
     `NSString *fromTime=@"11:30";
       NSString *toTime=@"12:30";`

I want that in time format, i tried using NSDateFormatter,

```
   `NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSDate *from=[df dateFromString:fromTime];
    NSLog(@"from %@",from);
    NSDate *to=[df dateFromString:toTime];
    NSLog(@"to %@",to);`
```

Output:
   from 1970-01-01 06:00:00 +0000
   to 1970-01-01 07:00:00 +0000

But i want only the time.

Answer (score 1):

A `NSDate` is a full date object, it will always contain a full date and time.
It will also return a date with GMT as the timezone (`+0000` part after the time).

You can just ignore the date part and just use the time part.

Comment: how to ignore the date part and just use the time part? Can you provide me a sample code?

Comment: Just use the `NSDateFormatter` when creating a string from the date and set the dateformat to `HH:mm` and you will get a string without the date part.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method `stringFromDate`

```
         NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        NSDate *from=[df dateFromString:fromTime];
        NSLog(@"from %@",[df stringFromDate:from]);
        NSDate *to=[df dateFromString:toTime];
        NSLog(@"to %@",[df stringFromDate:to]);
```